# Restore a dacpac file from a Linux command line

Tags: sql-server

I am in the process of moving an SQL Server database from a locally installed instance to a docker container. I have a bunch of dacpac files so I can restore my databases without data (data restoration comes later).

I am using the official Microsoft SQL Server Linux container. When I `docker exec -it /bin/bash` into the container, I want to restore the dacpac file with the command line. The only examples I see use SQL Management Studio or Powershell. Is it possible to restore a dacpac with the command line in Linux?

Comment: maybe the `sqlcmd` be useful for you: `docker exec -it <you-comtainer-name> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "<YourStrong@Passw0rd>" -Q "your-command"`

Comment: I'm not sure `sqlcmd` has DACPAC support, @mostafa8026 .

Comment: so use this docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/markhobson/sqlpackage

Comment: Thanks @mostafa8026 , I did not know that sqlpackage exists. I might be able to use it.

Comment: @mostafa8026 your answer helped me too. I took the example from that docker image documentation. I had to use "publish" instead of "export".